# Connect to my ISP ONT

Tags: networking, fiber

My ISP (Vodafone Italy) brings me a 1000/200 connection via the fiber.

Anyhow their router sucks, crashes often, and is not able to keep up with the traffic.

They use an Huawei Echolife HG8010 as optical network terminal, which converts fiber to copper for the vodafone router.

Can I connect directly to my ONT and bypass my ISP router? (I would connect in cascade after the main router).

How can I do that? When I try to connect my laptop to the ONT it can't even negotiate an IP. What should I configure?

Comment: Connect a PC to the ISP router and see if it's trying to use VLANs, PPPoE, or some magic DHCP options?

Comment: what should I look for?